# Shopware Stopwatch error when trying to deactivate plugin

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6

I installed `FroshDevelopmentHelper` Plugin and when I tried to deactivate it I got that error:

```
[Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError]                                                              
  Compile Error: Cannot declare class Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Stopwatch, because the name is already in use
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's an issue with the dependencies. You should head over to [the repository on GitHub](https://github.com/FriendsOfShopware/FroshDevelopmentHelper) and open an issue ticket there. There's likely not a lot you can do to solve that on your own.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is deleting the plugin files. I broke a shop after an update from 6.4 to 6.5 with that same error. I deleted the folder:

custom/plugins/FroshDevelopmentHelper

In the database I had no entry from the plugin so I did not have to delete anything over there.

Hope that helps.